# Query Collection of all XML Elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm looking to parse an XML file, and have the ability to search any element.

My XML code looks rather nontraditional (out of my control):

```
<DiagReport>
<LicensingData>
  <ToolVersion>6.3.9431.0</ToolVersion>
  <LicensingStatus>SL_LICENSING</LicensingStatus>
</LicensingData>
<Health>
  <Result>PASS</Result>
  <TamperedItems></TamperedItems>
</Health>
<Genuine>
  <ServerProps>GenuineId</ServerProps>
</Genuine>
</DiagReport>
```

I'd like to load each singular element into a collection, i.e. one collection including  `ToolVersion`, `Result`, etc. From there, I'd like to iterate through each element/name pair, and depending upon the element, do something different:

```
if (element.Equals(Result))
    //do something with "PASS"
```

Is this possible to do with LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML to iterate through all second level elements:

```
  var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test.xml");
    foreach (var element in xdoc.Element("DiagReport").Elements().Elements())
    {
        if (element.Name == "Result")
        {
            string value = element.Value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq to Xml` to query your `Xml` document, you can search `Elements`, `Attributes` and grab what you need.

More information can be found here: [Basic Queries (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx)

And you can creat simple querys like below.

```
  XElement root = XElement.Parse(File.ReadAllText("C:\\Test.xml"));
  var test = new 
  {
      ToolVersion = root.Descendants("ToolVersion").FirstOrDefault().Value,
      Result = root.Descendants("Result").FirstOrDefault().Value
  };
```