# Use Separate Elements From XML File

Tags: c#, xml, linq

In the below XML file, the elements that needs to be utilized together are broken up between `XElements`. (This is beyond my control). For example, I would like to use `ToolVersion` in conjunction with `Result`.

```
<DiagReport>
<LicensingData>
  <ToolVersion>6.3.9431.0</ToolVersion>
  <LicensingStatus>SL_LICENSING</LicensingStatus>
</LicensingData>
<Health>
  <Result>PASS</Result>
  <TamperedItems></TamperedItems>
</Health>
<Genuine>
  <ServerProps>GenuineId</ServerProps>
</Genuine>
</DiagReport>
```

I know how to get the deepest children from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537604/query-collection-of-all-xml-elements/17537886?noredirect=1#17537886), but this iterates one by one. In the example above, I might need `ToolVersion` and `Result`, but then need to go back to `LicensingStatus`, and pick up where I left off. (The code doesn't need to explicitly ignore `Result`, since I can just ignore that in my `switch` statements.

Is this possible?

Comment: so you just want to flatten `LicensingData` and `Health` into a single object?

Comment: I guess that would be one way of looking at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse it into an XmlDocument, then pull the values you require with XPath:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(yourXmlString);
string toolVersion = xml.SelectSingleNode("/DiagReport/LicensingData/ToolVersion").InnerText;
string result = xml.SelectSingleNode("/DiagReport/Health/Result").InnerText
```

You can learn more about XPath at [W3Schools XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp).

Or you can use XDocument:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(yourXmlString);
string toolVersion = xml.Element("DiagReport").Element("LicensingData").Element("ToolVersion").Value;
string result = xml.Element("DiagReport").Element("Health").Element("Result").Value;
```

Note that this assumes that all of the referenced elements exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can just loop though all the `DiagReport` elemets and select the values from `LicensingData` and `Health` that you need.

In this example they are just stored in a anonymous object, but you can create your own typed object is required.

```
  var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test.xml");
  var results = xmlDocument.Elements("DiagReport").Select(x => new 
  {
      ToolVersion = x.Descendants("ToolVersion").FirstOrDefault().Value,
      LicensingStatus = x.Descendants("LicensingStatus").FirstOrDefault().Value,
      Result = x.Descendants("Result").FirstOrDefault().Value
  });

  // print results
  foreach (var item in results)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("ToolVersion: {0}, LicensingData: {1}, Result: {2}", item.ToolVersion, item.LicensingStatus, item.Result);
  }
```

Comment: Understood, but that might start to cause issues with timing and memory. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: If `ToolVersion` or `LicensingStatus` or `Result` are duplicated anywhere in the tree, this may not produce the expected results.  If you are sure they will occur once (and only once) then it's good

Comment: @MichaelBray, there was no metion of duplicate elements in the question, however I thought he had a collection of `DiagReport` but I guess he has only one `DiagReport` element in the xml, so simply fetching the 3 values he needs(like in your answer) will be fine in his case.

Comment: @sa_ddam213: oh yes I see what you were doing now - iterating over each possible `DiagReport`.  I missed that the first time I looked.  Of course, it still assumes that there's only one of the three I mentioned, but then again, so does my answer (which also assumes only one `DiagReport`).  :)